# Mi código js se ejecuta 2 veces Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

tengo un problema con una página en la que estoy trabajando, hace cierto tiempo funcionaba bien, pero deje el proyecto sin tocar por una semana y cuando intente volver a ejecutarlo me dio un error que antes no me daba, el código js me daba errores, en consola me mostraba el siguiente mensaje:

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:
> Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as , as they will not be parsed.

Y lo que hice fue agregar `type="application/javascript"` y ya me funciono, pero ahora el código se ejecuta 2 veces, si coloco un `console.log('Hola')` esto es lo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encuentro ninguna razón para que se dupliquen las acciónes, este es mi archivo:

```html
<div class="uk-container uk-container-small uk-width-1-3 uk-align-left">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
        <h3 class="uk-card-title">Registrar Accidente</h3>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="button" id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="uk-container uk-container-small uk-width-3-3 uk-align-center">
    <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
        <h3 class="uk-card-title">Accidentes Registrados</h3>
        <table class="uk-table uk-table-divider">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Dirección</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Observación</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                $accidentes = DB::table('accidentes')->get();
                foreach ($accidentes as $accidente) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $accidente->direccion }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $accidente->fecha }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $accidente->observacion }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        console.log('Hola');
        document.getElementById('btnRegistrar').addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('clic');
            let html = `
            <!doctype html>
            <html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
            <head>
                <title>Registrar Accidente</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.15.6/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="app" class="uk-padding">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('accidentes.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Direccion</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input class="uk-input" id="form-stacked-text" type="text" placeholder="Direccion" name="direccion">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Fecha</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input class="uk-input" id="form-stacked-text" type="datetime" placeholder="Fecha" name="fecha" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Placas</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input class="uk-input" id="form-stacked-text" type="text" placeholder="Placas" name="placas">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">N° Licencia</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input class="uk-input" id="form-stacked-text" type="text" placeholder="Número de licencia" name="licencia">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Observación</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <textarea class="uk-textarea" rows="5" placeholder="Observación" name="observacion"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <label class="uk-form-label" for="imagen">Imagen</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <input class="uk-input" id="imagen" type="file" placeholder="Imagen" name="imagen">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text">Preview</label>
                            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                                <img id="preview" src="https://www.chemica-us.com/1187-thickbox_default/472-gris-raton.jpg" alt="Preview" class="uk-width-1-1" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="uk-margin">
                            <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="submit" id="registrar">Registrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>
            `;
            let ventana = window.open("", "ventana", "width=600,height=600");
            ventana.document.write(html);
            ventana.onbeforeunload = function() {
                ventana.close();
                location.reload();
            }
            ventana.document.getElementById('registrar').addEventListener('click', function() {
                ventana.close();
                location.reload();
            });
            ventana.document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
                let fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
                let files = e.target.files;
                let img = ventana.document.getElementById("preview");
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
                img.onload = function() {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Según el código anterior lo que hace es que al darle clic a `btnRegistrar` crear una ventana con un pequeño formulario, lo que pasa es que se realiza 2 veces la acción y la ventana se crea con 2 formularios.

Solo me pasa en las pestañas que cuentan con una etiqueta `<script>`, y no entiendo por que, en la pagina de inicio tengo lo siguiente:

```html
<?php
            if (isset($_GET['tab'])) {
                if ($_GET['tab'] == 'registrar') {
                    ?>
                    @include('registrar')
                    <?php
                } else if ($_GET['tab'] == 'verificar') {
                    ?>
                    @include('verificar')
                    <?php
                }
            }
?>
```

Utilizo laravel 8, php 7.4.2, Vue 2.6.12, Vue lo utilizo para el login con autentificación que posee laravel.

De antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: El primer "Hola" proviene de la carga normal del documento, y el segundo "hola" proviene de una llamada ajax (fíjate en el VM1087:3, que indica que es código ejecutado aparte con ajax).  Investiga a ver si realizas alguna acción asíncrona que esté recargandolo todo sin querer.

Comment: @masterguru estuve revisando pero no encontré ninguna realimentación, lo que hice para resolverlo momentáneamente es agregar el script por separado y llamarlo abajo en el documento de inicio, el problema es que cargo código js innecesario para otras pestañas

Comment: Ahorita cambie el `type` a `module` nuevamente y ya funciono de nuevo, cada vez estoy mas confundido, antes con module no funcionaba, así tengo momentáneamente mi script `<script src="{{ asset('js/register.js') }}" type="module" defer></script>`, pero esta vez lo cargo desde `register.blade.php`.

Comment: uf, yo de modules y laravel poco, lo siento, lo que dije en mi comentario inicial se basaba en mi experiencia mirando la consola cuando lanzo mis ajax (eso del VMxxxx) pero creo que poco más podré ayudarte. Suerte! :-)

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias igualmente